# Selecting Object.keys in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Wondering if someone can help me with the below JS? I am trying to map data from an API

```
var result = Object.keys(data).map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), data[k]]);
```

This works well on an array like

```
{"2017-12-26":0,"2017-12-27":26,"2017-12-28":0}
```

but not if the array is

```
{"2017-12-21":{"nb_pageviews":10,"nb_uniq_pageviews":4,"nb_downloads":0,"nb_uniq_downloads":0,"nb_outlinks":4,"nb_uniq_outlinks":2,"nb_searches":0,"nb_keywords":0,"avg_time_generation":0.299},"2017-12-22":{"nb_pageviews":8,"nb_uniq_pageviews":4,"nb_downloads":0,"nb_uniq_downloads":0,"nb_outlinks":1,"nb_uniq_outlinks":1,"nb_searches":0,"nb_keywords":0,"avg_time_generation":0.453}}
```

How can I get just the data for `nb_pageviews` and the `value` for each date?

This is to be used in a NVD3 Chart as

```js
d3.json(`https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.getVisits&idSite=2&period=day&date=last30&format=json&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`, function(data1) {
  d3.json(`https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.getUniqueVisitors&idSite=2&period=day&date=last30&format=json&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`, function(data2) {
    d3.json(`https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.getActions&idSite=2&period=day&date=last30&format=json&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`, function(data3) {
      d3.json(`https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.getBounceCount&idSite=2&period=day&date=last30&format=json&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`, function(data4) {
        d3.json(`https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=last30&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`, function(data5) {

          var result = Object.keys(data1).map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), data1[k]]);
          data1 = {
            "key": "Visits",
            "values": result
          };
          var result = Object.keys(data2).map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), data2[k]]);
          data2 = {
            "key": "Unique Visits",
            "values": result
          };
          var result = Object.keys(data3).map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), data3[k]]);
          data3 = {
            "key": "Actions",
            "values": result
          };
          var result = Object.keys(data4).map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), data4[k]]);
          data4 = {
            "key": "Bounces",
            "values": result
          };
          var result = Object.keys(data5)
            .filter(k => !isNaN(data5[k].nb_pageviews))
            .map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), data5[k].nb_pageviews]);
          data5 = {
            "key": "Page Views",
            "values": result
          };

          var data = [];
          data.push(data1);
          data.push(data2);
          data.push(data3);
          data.push(data4);
          data.push(data5);


          (function() {

            nv.addGraph(function() {

              var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                .margin({
                  left: 45,
                  right: 30
                })
                .x(function(d) {
                  return d[0]
                })
                .y(function(d) {
                  return d[1]
                })

                .useInteractiveGuideline(true);


              chart.xAxis
                .tickFormat(function(d) {
                  return d3.time.format('%m/%d/%y')(new Date(d))
                });

              chart.yAxis
                .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

              chart.yAxis.tickPadding(15);
              chart.xAxis.tickPadding(15);



              d3.select('#summaryChart svg')
                .datum(data)
                .transition().duration(500)
                .call(chart);

              nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

              $('#summaryChart').data('chart', chart);

              return chart;
            });

          })();
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#summaryChart {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.6/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.6/nv.d3.js"></script>


<div id="summaryChart" class="line-chart text-center" data-x-grid="false">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Second one doesn't look valid, key is missing from the beginning.

Comment: Is the JSON data provided even a valid json format?

Comment: It is from here - https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=last30&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff

Comment: I made an error copying from the above link. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your method to access the `data[k].nb_pageviews`

```
var result = Object.keys(data).map(k => [ new Date(k).getTime(), data[k].nb_pageviews ]);
```

Some of the dates have no `nb_pageviews` properties against them, so you may want to filter them out as well

```
var result = Object.keys( data )
      .filter( k => !isNaN( data[k].nb_pageviews ) )
      .map(k => [ new Date(k).getTime(), data[k].nb_pageviews ] );
```

**Edit**

If want '0' instead of filtering out those dates which doesn't have `nb_pageviews` property then make it

```
data[k].nb_pageviews || 0
```

or

```
isNaN( data[k].nb_pageviews ) ? 0 : data[k].nb_pageviews || 0
```

Finally

```
var result = Object.keys( data )
      .map(k => [ new Date(k).getTime(), ( data[k].nb_pageviews || 0 ) ] );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, will mark as answered when it allows me. If a simple request, how about if I wanted the dates that have no `nb_pageviews` properties to show `0`. The data is being used on a chart and causes blank spaces.

Comment: @Darren My bad, I have updated the code. Basically i need to check `isNaN`.

Comment: Steller... Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, the updated code is showing gaps where the property is empty. Is there another way to add these empty properties a `0`?

Comment: I updated my question to include the chart being used so you can see what I mean in detail. Thanks in advance for your further help.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again.